# Section index working but not visible on a table in a monotouch application

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm reading through the [Professional iPhone Programming with MonoTouch and .NET/C#](http://au.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-047063782X.html)  book, but I'm having trouble getting the example with section indexes with tables working. The book has [sample code available](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-iPhone-Programming-with-MonoTouch-and-NET-C-.productCd-047063782X,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html).

When I try to run the code in chapter 6 ([download here](http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/2X/04706378/DOWNLOAD/637827_c06_download_New.zip)) in the folder "Tables03", no section index is displayed  however the index still appears to function when I slide my finger down it. There is also a gap where it should be, just no letters are there. See below, I'm scrolling using the index but no letters are visible.

Has there been a change in the api that has broken this since the book was released? Or is the problem something else?

(Note to run the code I had to change the iPhone Build SDK version in project settings, since it was using 3.0).

[image: table problem]

Comment: if you are using MT 4.0, you might be seeing this bug - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627039/indexed-tableviews-not-displaying-after-upgrade-to-mt-4-0

Comment: @Jason, thanks, that is exactly the problem, and using the code at https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=684281#c4 fixed the problem for me. Do you want to post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=684281) with MT 4.0.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627039/indexed-tableviews-not-displaying-after-upgrade-to-mt-4-0)

Answer (score 0):

You have to fill out the section index names.

An is example is [here](http://ksheffield.com/blog/?p=22).

I'm not sure why your book's examples aren't doing this--I have found bugs in certain book examples myself.

Comment: The sample had an implementation for ''SectionIndexTitles''. Also, the code at that site causes a segfault for me when I try to run it. Maybe it is a bug introduced with the new 4.0 monotouch library?